# Openlayers popup autoPan on map with padding

Tags: css, openlayers

I have a map with left-padding of n-pixels. That value is changed based on some factors. My problem is that popup (overlay) on map that uses autoPan: true sees that padding as still usable for map and pans itself wrong.

I've created similar situation here:
https://codepen.io/bobbysz/pen/aeWQNb

If i remove this, behaviour is OK.

```
padding-left: 360px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes please remove padding-left and add display inline-table for ol-viewport class.

**css**

```
.map{
padding-left:0;
}
.ol-viewport{
display:inline-table;
}
```